# Getting OpenFlow rules from a datapath

Tags: sdn, openflow, ryu

In Ryu Controller, for a selected datapath, how can I get the OpenFlow rules from the switch? For example, for the rule below:

> cookie=0x0, duration=18575.528s, table=0, n_packets=1, n_bytes=98,
>   priority=1,ip,in_port=3,nw_dst=10.0.0.1 actions=output:1

I want to get nw_dst and actions fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the **OFPTableStatsRequest** object.  It will return a list with all the installed flows.

Note there is also an **OFPGroupStatsRequest** that does the same thing for groups.

An untested example that relies on an instance variable **datapath**.

```
import ryu.app.ofctl.api as api

def ofdpaTableStatsRequest(datapath):
    parser = datapath.ofproto_parser
    return parser.OFPTableStatsRequest(datapath)

def getFlows(self):
    """
    Obtain a list of Flows loaded on the switch
    `
    :return: A list of Flow Entires
    """
    msg = ofdpaTableStatsRequest(self.datapath)
    reply = api.send_msg(self.ryuapp, msg,
                         reply_cls=self.parser.OFPTableStatsReply,
                         reply_multi=True)
    // the flow entries you are looking for will be in the reply
```

Let me know if this works for you

Comment: Yes it works, thank you. Also I solved it inside the event handler. For example:
@set_ev_cls(ofp_event.EventOFPFlowStatsReply, MAIN_DISPATCHER)
    def flowStatsHandler(self, ev):
        body = ev.msg.body
        for flow in body:
             self.ipv4Dest = flow.match['ipv4_dst']